# What is the difference between readonly and prop without setter?

Tags: c#

As in title: **what is the difference between:**

```
private readonly string name = "ourName";
```

and

```
private string name { get { return "ourName" } }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version is part of the state of the object - it's just a field. It can still be changed within the constructor body, too.

The second version is *just* a property - it's effectively a method which returns the same value every time you call it, and isn't really part of the state of the object. (There's no field involved.)

Comment: this is just elegant , better than MSDN explanation @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The first is a field.  The second is a property.  The field holds the value "ourName" as local state.  The property provides a method stateless accessing the literal "ourName".

You can set the field and mutate the state of the field in a constructor.  You can also pass the field to a `ref` or `out` parameter of a method in the constructor.

None of these statements are true about the property.  All you can do with the property is read the value returned by invoking the underlying `get_name()` method (which always returns the same literal value "ourName".  Furthermore, consider these examples to see how the field case can be used in contrast to the property:

```
public class ExampleWithField
{ 
    public ExampleWithField(){ 
        this.name = "Not our name"; // the value will be "Not our name"
    }
    private readonly string name = "ourName";

}

public class ExampleWithFieldAndRefParam
{ 
    public ExampleWithFieldAndRefParam(){ 
        SetRefValue(ref this.name); // the value will be "Not our nameourName"
    }
    static void SetRefValue(ref string value){ value = "Not our name" + value; }
    private readonly string name = "ourName";

}

public class ExampleWithFieldAndOutParam
{ 
    public ExampleWithFieldAndOutParam(){ 
        SetOutValue(out this.name); // the value will be "Not our name"
    }
    static void SetOutValue(out string value){ value = "Not our name"; }
    private readonly string name = "ourName";

}
public class ExampleWithProperty
{ 
    public ExampleWithProperty(){ 
        this.name = "Not our name"; // this will not compile.
    }
    private string name { get { return "ourName"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you use reflection or serialization, it will behave different, ie: the GetProperties() method won't return the field in the first case and the field won't be serialized on the last one.

Answer (score 0):

readonly field can be initialized/set in constructor.
property with only get works like function. can not be set in common case

Answer (score 0):

A `readonly` field could be assigned to by a constructor. A property with no `set` method couldn't be assigned to by anything.

Answer (score 0):

this is a field declaration that can only be set during declaration:

```
readonly string name = "abc";
```

or inside of a the class constructor.

Properties on the other hand are like syntactic sugar for methods. (i.e. get is for getFoo() and set is for setFoo(object value).

so the following line is actually compiled to a single method:

```
string name { get { return "xyz"; } }
```

this is why you cannot use properties as values to `out` or `ref` parameters